# Insert NULL values on DB (method)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**UPDATE----**

Afer using this method:

```
                        foreach($_POST as $k => $v) { 
  $params[] = empty($v)? "NULL":$v;
} 

$params_string_values = "'" . implode("','",$params) . "'";
$param_name_list = "tu_id,tu_status,tu_name,tu_fk_tt_id,tu_mon_1_s,tu_mon_1_e,tu_mon_2_s,tu_mon_2_e,tu_mon_3_s,tu_mon_3_e,tu_tue_1_s,tu_tue_1_e,tu_tue_2_s,tu_tue_2_e,tu_tue_3_s,tu_tue_3_e,tu_wed_1_s,tu_wed_1_e,tu_wed_2_s,tu_wed_2_e,tu_wed_3_s,tu_wed_3_e,tu_thu_1_s,tu_thu_1_e,tu_thu_2_s,tu_thu_2_e,tu_thu_3_s,tu_thu_3_e,tu_fri_1_s,tu_fri_1_e,tu_fri_2_s,tu_fri_2_e,tu_fri_3_s,tu_fri_3_e,tu_sat_1_s,tu_sat_1_e,tu_sat_2_s,tu_sat_2_e,tu_sat_3_s,tu_sat_3_e,tu_sun_1_s,tu_sun_1_e,tu_sun_2_s,tu_sun_2_e,tu_sun_3_s,tu_sun_3_e";
$param_values = "'','1',{$params_string_values}";

$insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT into turn_conf( {$param_name_list} ) values ({$param_values})");
```

It creates a valid query as it seems (here I paste it), but no NULL value is stored on databse, all NULL values go to database as "00:00":

```
INSERT into turn_conf( tu_id,tu_status,tu_name,tu_fk_tt_id,tu_mon_1_s,tu_mon_1_e,tu_mon_2_s,tu_mon_2_e,tu_mon_3_s,tu_mon_3_e,tu_tue_1_s,tu_tue_1_e,tu_tue_2_s,tu_tue_2_e,tu_tue_3_s,tu_tue_3_e,tu_wed_1_s,tu_wed_1_e,tu_wed_2_s,tu_wed_2_e,tu_wed_3_s,tu_wed_3_e,tu_thu_1_s,tu_thu_1_e,tu_thu_2_s,tu_thu_2_e,tu_thu_3_s,tu_thu_3_e,tu_fri_1_s,tu_fri_1_e,tu_fri_2_s,tu_fri_2_e,tu_fri_3_s,tu_fri_3_e,tu_sat_1_s,tu_sat_1_e,tu_sat_2_s,tu_sat_2_e,tu_sat_3_s,tu_sat_3_e,tu_sun_1_s,tu_sun_1_e,tu_sun_2_s,tu_sun_2_e,tu_sun_3_s,tu_sun_3_e ) values ('','1','12345555','1','10:00','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL')
```

This is what it records on DB:

### [image: record]

---

---

I have this query, in which sometimes variables `'$va1'`, `'$val2'` and `'$val3'` will have no value:

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO turn_conf (tu_id,value1,value2,value3) VALUES ('','$va1','$val2','$val3')") or die (mysql_error());
```

In case any of these variables have no value stored, anything related to it must be sent to the DB (in order to store a NULL value on DB), for exampe if only `'$val1'` stores info, the final query must be:

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO turn_conf (tu_id,value1) VALUES ('','$va1')") or die (mysql_error());
```

To solve this I have created an structure for each variable, checking wether it stores something or not, and in case it doesn't, just declarating nothing and sending nothing:

```
if ($_POST['value1'] == ""){
    $val1_p = "";
    $val1_s = ""; 
}else {
    $val1_p = ",value1";
    $val1_sv = $_POST['value1'];
    $val1_s = ", '$val1_sv'" ;}  

if ($_POST['value2'] == ""){
    $val2_p = "";
    $val2_s = ""; 
}else {
    $val2_p = ",value2";
    $val2_sv = $_POST['value2'];
    $val2_s = ", '$val2_sv'" ;}  

if ($_POST['value3'] == ""){
    $val3_p = "";
    $val3_s = ""; 
}else {
    $val3_p = ",value3";
    $val3_sv = $_POST['value3'];
    $val3_s = ", '$val3_sv'" ;}
```

and:

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO turn_conf (tu_id $val1_p $val2_p $val3_p) VALUES ('' $val1_s $val2_s $val3_s)") or die (mysql_error());
```

This works, and creates the right query, but id like to know **if you find ths method proper, or if it would be better to choose another more efficient one**. Please not in this example I used only 3 variables, but this query on real has 43 variables, I make this question due to the amount of data.

Comment: Have you looked into [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)?

Comment: as @Mureinik suggest use prepared statements, and allow NULL value insert so if you have no correct value simple insert NULL.

Comment: @Daan this is working now perfectly by this way, whats wrong with it?

Comment: Obviously the mysql_* functions you use.

Comment: @gafreax, thank you i'll take a look now at it. NULL values are allowed on this DB fields but if I send a emty value, DB takes "00:00:00" value (these are time value type fields)

Comment: i repeat, this is working properly @Daan, if there is an specific mistake or error just tell me which, that would be helpful.

Comment: @Daan with this ethod, in case only $val1 stores something, final query that generates and inserts properfly is: INSERT INTO turn_conf (tu_id ,value1 ) VALUES ('', '10:00' ) or die...

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated. Don't use them use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO turn_conf (tu_id,value1,value2,value3) VALUES ('','".((isset($va1))?"'".$va1."'":"NULL")."','".((isset($va2))?"'".$va2."'":"NULL")."','".((isset($va3))?"'".$va3."'":"NULL")."')") or die (mysql_error());
```

Basically you want to test if the value is set. We use the short if-notation for this:

```
isset($va1)?"'".$va1."'":"NULL"
```

If $va1 is set (has a value), we will put "'value'" in the query, otherwise "NULL" for an empty value.

If you want to test on an empty string too:

```
(isset($va1) && $va1 != '')?"'".$va1."'":"NULL"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use prepared statement Try this:

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) { 
  $params[] = empty($v)? "NULL":$v;
} 
mysql_query("insert into turn_conf(field1,field2...) values(" . implode(",",$params).  ");
```

If you use prepared statement (better!) try something like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $v) {
 $params[] = $v;
}
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO turn_conf (tu_id $val1_p $val2_p $val3_p) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$sth->execute($params);
```

So simple!

PS: This is an example but doesn't use directly $_POST value, filter it before (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php, and http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php). example:

```
$field_int= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'field1', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

UPDATE

you use this code:

```
 $insert = mysql_query("INSERT into turn_conf(tu_id,tu_name,tu_status,tu_fk_tt_id,tu_mon_1_s,tu_mon_1_e,tu_mon_2_s,t‌​u_mon_2_e,tu_mon_3_s,tu_mon_3_e,tu_tue_1_s,tu_tue_1_e,tu_tue_2_s,tu_tue_2_e,tu_tu‌​e_3_s,tu_tue_3_e,tu_wed_1_s,tu_wed_1_e,tu_wed_2_s,tu_wed_2_e,tu_wed_3_s,tu_wed_3_‌​e,tu_thu_1_s,tu_thu_1_e,tu_thu_2_s,tu_thu_2_e,tu_thu_3_s,tu_thu_3_e,tu_fri_1_s,tu‌​_fri_1_e,tu_fri_2_s,tu_fri_2_e,tu_fri_3_s,tu_fri_3_e,tu_sat_1_s,tu_sat_1_e,tu_sat‌​_2_s,tu_sat_2_e,tu_sat_3_s,tu_sat_3_e,tu_sun_1_s) values('','$newTurnName','1','$newTurnType'," . implode(",",$params). "))")
```

but change it like this:

```
$params_string_values = "'" . implode("','",$params) . "'";
$param_name_list = "tu_id,tu_name,tu_status,tu_fk_tt_id,tu_mon_1_s,tu_mon_1_e,tu_mon_2_s,t‌​u_mon_2_e,tu_mon_3_s,tu_mon_3_e,tu_tue_1_s,tu_tue_1_e,tu_tue_2_s,tu_tue_2_e,tu_tu‌​e_3_s,tu_tue_3_e,tu_wed_1_s,tu_wed_1_e,tu_wed_2_s,tu_wed_2_e,tu_wed_3_s,tu_wed_3_‌​e,tu_thu_1_s,tu_thu_1_e,tu_thu_2_s,tu_thu_2_e,tu_thu_3_s,tu_thu_3_e,tu_fri_1_s,tu‌​_fri_1_e,tu_fri_2_s,tu_fri_2_e,tu_fri_3_s,tu_fri_3_e,tu_sat_1_s,tu_sat_1_e,tu_sat‌​_2_s,tu_sat_2_e,tu_sat_3_s,tu_sat_3_e,tu_sun_1_s";
$param_values = "'','{$newTurnName}','1','{$newTurnType}',{$param_string_values}";

$insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT into turn_conf( {$param_name_list} ) values ({$param_values})");
```

Comment: I am about to learn about prepared statements and try this method in case of success Ill tick. ill keep you informed, thank you for your attention :)

Comment: thank you! give me a feedback if u have success or not:D

Comment: I have choosen the first option, ant it gives me this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':00,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,N' at line 1

Comment: This is the query: $insert = mysql_query("INSERT into turn_conf(tu_id,tu_name,tu_status,tu_fk_tt_id,tu_mon_1_s,tu_mon_1_e,tu_mon_2_s,tu_mon_2_e,tu_mon_3_s,tu_mon_3_e,tu_tue_1_s,tu_tue_1_e,tu_tue_2_s,tu_tue_2_e,tu_tue_3_s,tu_tue_3_e,tu_wed_1_s,tu_wed_1_e,tu_wed_2_s,tu_wed_2_e,tu_wed_3_s,tu_wed_3_e,tu_thu_1_s,tu_thu_1_e,tu_thu_2_s,tu_thu_2_e,tu_thu_3_s,tu_thu_3_e,tu_fri_1_s,tu_fri_1_e,tu_fri_2_s,tu_fri_2_e,tu_fri_3_s,tu_fri_3_e,tu_sat_1_s,tu_sat_1_e,tu_sat_2_s,tu_sat_2_e,tu_sat_3_s,tu_sat_3_e,tu_sun_1_s) values('','$newTurnName','1','$newTurnType'," . implode(",",$params).  "))");

Comment: change `implode(",",$params)` with `"'" . implode("','",$params)`. Let me know if it works

Comment: After changing it like you see down here, it says that "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1", this is due to a non equal number of variables and arguments, why?

Comment: $inser = mysql_query("INSERT into turn_conf(tu_id,tu_name,tu_status,tu_fk_tt_id,tu_mon_1_s,tu_mon_1_e,tu_mon_2_s,tu_mon_2_e,tu_mon_3_s,tu_mon_3_e,tu_tue_1_s,tu_tue_1_e,tu_tue_2_s,tu_tue_2_e,tu_tue_3_s,tu_tue_3_e,tu_wed_1_s,tu_wed_1_e,tu_wed_2_s,tu_wed_2_e,tu_wed_3_s,tu_wed_3_e,tu_thu_1_s,tu_thu_1_e,tu_thu_2_s,tu_thu_2_e,tu_thu_3_s,tu_thu_3_e,tu_fri_1_s,tu_fri_1_e,tu_fri_2_s,tu_fri_2_e,tu_fri_3_s,tu_fri_3_e,tu_sat_1_s,tu_sat_1_e,tu_sat_2_s,tu_sat_2_e,tu_sat_3_s,tu_sat_3_e,tu_sun_1_s,tu_sun_1_e,tu_sun_2_s) values('','$newTurnName','1','$newTurnType'," . "'" . implode("','",$params). "'" . ")");

Comment: Please see update on question. almost there but finally it does not take the NULL values, it sets them to "00:00" isntead of NULL.

Comment: @Biomehanika you must set NULL as default value for date field.Do something like this: `ALTER TABLE turn_conf MODIFY date_type_colname DATETIME DEFAULT NULL;`

Comment: All these fields are set to default Null, are not DATETIMEs are only TIME values: http://i.imgur.com/GxHmWrJ.png

Comment: it's strange behaviour. It's a primary key? Or this field have some constraints?

Comment: not at all... would this not be because of the ' sybol before and after each NULL?

Comment: @Biomehanika, yess: if you try to insert `'NULL'` the db insert a default value (like 00:00). If your variable are not valid insert `NULL` without `'` symbol

Comment: That seems not possible by your system, as it is not posssible to distingüish between empty values (in order to avoid the ') and not empty values. I'll think about how to make this